# "git add" problem: last line is always redone when appending more lines

Tags: git

My problem is that after I run `git add`, the last line is always redone. See example below:

Initially, the file already contained "1".

1. Add "2" in file
2. Run `git add`
3. Check staged changes with `git diff --cached`
4. Shows that "1" is deleted and added again, then, "2" is added

```
$ git add .
$ git diff --cached
diff --git a/file-a.txt b/file-a.txt
index 56a6051..7a754f4 100644
--- a/file-a.txt
+++ b/file-a.txt
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
-1
\ No newline at end of file
+1
+2
\ No newline at end of file
```

I don't want that "1" is deleted and added again because it was there initially.

Comment: The line in red has indeed been deleted *as it is*. A very similar new line (the same plus a "new line" character at the end) has been added. Nothing unusual, be reassured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line containing "1" is shown as deleted and re-added, because in the original file the line was one character `1`, without a line break, and in the changed file the line is two characters `1\n`, with a line break.

Git is telling you that the last line of your file does not end with a line break, because this should usually be the case (see [Why should text files end with a newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline)). You should adjust the settings of your text editor to ensure that files end with a line break. That will avoid the issue you have observed.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing that because the file did not have an `EOL` to close that line that has `1`, so the file is really like this:

```
1<EOF>
```

The `<EOF>` is not really there, it's just to mark that the file *ends* there. But now, the file looks like this:

```
1<EOL>
2<EOF>
```

So, the line that had `1` *without an `<EOL>`* is gone replaced with a line with a line that has `1` *followed by an `<EOL>`*.